# How to use EventToCommand - Error in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

The user input something in the TextBox and hits the Enter-button. When the Enter-button is hit the `AddFieldCommand` is called. How do I do what in XAML?

My code is giving me a warning: "The Property 'Text' is set more than once".

I need to know which object in the Canvas that is being updated, so I can add the content from the TextBox to my model - this is why I use `EventToCommand`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" >
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" >
        </KeyBinding>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddField">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</TextBox>
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML, everything that’s placed inside an element becomes its *content*. For text boxes, this sets the `Text` property. This is to allow things like this:

```
<TextBox>Foo bar</TextBox>
```

So you can place the content within the XAML elements. This is equivalent to this:

```
<TextBox Text="Foo bar" />
```

Now, if you look at your XAML code, you will notice that you have two elements inside the `TextBox` element: `TextBox.InputBindings` and `i:EventTrigger`. To explain the first, you need to know that there is another way to specify an element’s property values, by using child elements. This makes the above examples equivalent to this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>Foo bar</TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

This works for all properties of `TextBox`. Now, `InputBindings` is an property of `TextBox`, so having it as a child element will correctly set the property and it will also not affect the element’s content value (so `Text` isn’t set by its presence). However, `i:EventTrigger` is not an property of TextBox, so this will set the content of the `TextBox`—giving the error message you see.

To use interaction event triggers, you need to place these into the attached property `i:Interaction.Triggers`. As an attached property, it can be set with a child element like above. So, your code should look like this:

```
<TextBox …>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="AddField">
            <cmd:EventToCommand … />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: But how do I trigger the `EventToCommand` when the user hits the Enter-button? And thanks a lot for your walkthrough!

Comment: By your setup, the command is now executed when the `AddField` event is raised. You need need to listen to the [`KeyPress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event then (and check whether the pressed key was the Enter key). You could subtype the `TextBox` and add a `EnterKeyPressed` event which you could then use the EventTrigger for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ICommand interface** to execute your command and use **IsDefault=true** property of the button which allows it to remain focus.So when you click enter it will execute the Command you binded on the button.

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtFields" Text="{Binding FieldsTextProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="23" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Background="#FFCBEECD" AcceptsReturn="False" />                            

      <Button Name="btnEnter" IsDefault="True" Command="{Binding DataContext.AddFieldCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Do you know a method without the button? I would like to trigger the `EventToCommand` every time the user hits 'Enter'.